# Redirecting from javascript to custom url in callback function with Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction

Tags: redirect, remote-action, urlfor

I have a custom visual force page. 
I use     `Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction` to post data and create a custom object on a custom Apex Controller extension.
This action creates my custom object and then returns it. I would like then to redirect to the newly created record page. I have been struggling to do that. Here's the javascript code :

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
  '{!$RemoteAction.TestController.saveFacture}',
   facture, factureDate.value, factureLines,
  function(result, event){
      console.log("in callback func");

        //redirect
        console.log(result);

       var url = '{! urlfor("facture__c", null)}';

  },
  {escape: true}
);
```

and here is the controller action Im calling :

```
  @RemoteAction
    public static Facture__c saveFacture(Facture__c facture, String factureDate, Ligne__c[] lines) {
        // Perform isUpdatable() checking first, then
        System.debug('facture: '+ facture);
        facture.date__c = date.valueOf(factureDate);
        upsert facture;
        for (Ligne__c line : lines){
            line.facture__c = facture.id;
            upsert line;
        }
        return facture;
    }
```

it returns a facture object that I can Use to build the url where I want to redirect on the client side (result.Id). However I cant find how to correctly build the url to redirect to. I ve been trying to use UrlFor unsuccessfully. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `URLFOR()` here, because your JavaScript remoting interactions happen outside the Visualforce rendering cycle. The `URLFOR()` function can't be executed in JavaScript on the client side, and when the page is rendered, you won't have the object details.

Instead, you can use standard JavaScript methods to navigate to a new page. An example is below.

If you're operating in a mobile or Lightning context, rather than setting `window.location.href`, you should use [`sforce.one.navigateToSObject`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm).

### Visualforce Example

```
<apex:page controller="TestRemoting">
    <script>
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.TestRemoting.runQuery}',
        function(result, event){
            console.log(result);
            window.location.href= '/' + result.Id;
        },
        {escape: true}
    );
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

### Apex Controller

```
public class TestRemoting {
    @RemoteAction
    public static Account runQuery() {
        return [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];
    }
}
```